# How to get data user input data from my webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have made a form in my site, which will allow me to get suggestions about Rubik's cube algorithms, but how to know what input the user has? For better understanding, I've given the code below:

```
<form method="POST">
        <label>Your name: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required><br><br>
        <label>Your E-mail: </label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" required><br><br>
        <label>Select puzzle: </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="2x2" value="2x2">2x2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="3x3" value="3x3">3x3<br><br>
        <label>Select set/subset: </label><br>
        <input list="set"><br><br>
        <datalist id="set">
            <option>Ortega OLL</option>
            <option>Ortega PBLL</option>
            <option>CLL</option>
            <option>EG-1</option>
            <option>EG-2</option>
            <option>F2L</option>
            <option>OLL</option>
            <option>PLL</option>
            <option>COLL</option>
            <option>WV</option>
        </datalist>
        <label>Your Alg: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="alg"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="w3-black w3-button w3-hover-white w3-hover-text-blue w3-text-white">
      </form>
```

Comment: The HTML code you posted the client side - you'll also need a server side to receive the data. So you'll need a scripting language like PHP on your server. HTML alone can not do what you want.

Comment: Are you posting the form to a specific page?

Comment: Your form needs an `action` - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Comment: The `action` attribute is not required with `HTML5`. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp @RobertSeaman

Comment: Thanks @blackandorangecat

Comment: @RobertSeaman Not that it's a bad idea to have it! But it's no longer required. A form without an action will be submitted to itself by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please add action attribute to your form tag and on submit here is the example

```
<form action="getvalue.php" method="post">

</form>
```

Note: Every form element must have unique name .

after adding action attribute then create getvalue.php file and add following code in to it

```
<?php 
    print_r($_POST);
```

?>
 Above code will give all the form field values

do let me know if it was helpfull...

Comment: I understood what you wanted to say. But won't putting an action attribute will make the getvalue.php page  load after the form is submitted?? I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Means you don't want to load page after summiting form right??

Comment: Exactly! After form submission, the user will get a notification(which is easy for me) but also I will be able to get what the user has input in the forms

Comment: In order to this the best way is to use ajax here is example.function testAjax() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "getvalue.php",  
      success: function(data) {
         return data; 
      }
   });
}

Comment: Ok. But if i use the PHP code above, how will I be able to see the data?? I mean from where??

Comment: on ajax success you will get the response from your php file where have printed your data u can get that and display as html() OR  append with some div or u can also console.log(data) for it ..

Comment: I tried that. But it still loads the getValue.php page. I don't want my user to be there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but here is an example of a form that submits to itself. This will allow you to remain on the same page after the form has been submitted. You can change what the user sees to indicate that the form was done successfully/etc. I have tested this code and it works.

```
<main>
    <?php

    // When the form is submitted
    if (isset($_POST["submitButton"])){

        //Do something with the data from the form - you don't have to print it out. 
        //This is all done on the server. 
        //Connect to DATABASE, send an EMAIL, VALIDATE the form, etc.

        print("<pre>");
        print_r($_POST);  // for all GET variables
        print("</pre>")

        ?>
        <!-- This HTML will be visible to the user after the form has been submitted. -->
        <h1>The form has been submitted successfully!</h1>
        <?php



    }else{  //If the form has not been submitted
        ?>

        <form method = "post" >
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" id = "submitButton" name = "submitButton" value="Submit">
        </form>


        <?php
    } //End else
    ?>

</main>
```